# how do you call function to pull data automaticall to chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to set up a interval on my data rerriveal and update my chart automatically. I tried the following but did not work. I am not getting any chart back. what am I doing wroing in the event: load function? Is this how it is done, any ideas greatly appreciated.

```
function server_cpu() {
        var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
         chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series;
                        setInterval(function() {
                        $.getJSON('db.php', function(data) {
                            series=data;
                            });
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                },
                zoomType: 'x'
            },

            exporting: {
            enabled: true
});
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
events: {
    load: function() {
        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function() {
            $.getJSON('db.php', function(data) {
                 series.setData(data);
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
},
```

1st, series is an array, so you'll want series[0].  2nd, you need to use setData to change the series data after the chart is drawn (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData())

It's not clear from your code if you're already doing it, but you will need to set the original series : [{data:[...]}]

Comment: I am getting this error: "Uncaught type error: cannot call method 'setData' of undefined, any ideas?

Comment: Does it render correctly the 1st time, and then throw that error after 1 second?  That error implies that series[0] doesn't exist.  Do you set series in the config object?  Try changing series.setData(data) to chart.series[0].setData(data).